# RewriteRule not actually work with xampp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

i wave the following pice of code in .htacces :

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /app/

RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^register/?$ register.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^recover/?$ recover.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^all/?$ home.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^chats/?$ chats.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^manage-photos/?$ manage-photos.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^friends/?$ friends.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^upgrades/?$ upgrades.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^gifts/([0-9]+)$ gifts.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^friends/([0-9]+)$ friends.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^chat/([0-9]+)$ chat.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$ page.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^settings/?$ settings.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^preferences/?$ preferences.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^profile-views/?$ profile-views.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^hot-list/?$ hot-list.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^process/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ process.php?t=$1 [NC,L]
```

i have xampp working , the module is enabled in httpd.conf .
i have in this conf the code:

```
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<directory />
Require all denied
AllowOverride none
</directory>
#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#
```

i didn't change this , all other AllowOverride are ALL ! , were is my problem , on every link i get Object not found .
what i want is that www.mydomain.com/site/APP/LOGIN to be available, ori www.mydomain.com/site/APP/LOGIN/profile/20 instead of profile.php?id=$1.
Ty

Comment: Is mod_rewrite active in Xampp ? also, check the error logs, maybe you can find a clue there.

Comment: yes, is on , i dont have nothing in any log :(

Comment: someone please to answer because i did it with the following :

RewriteBase subfolder/app/

RewriteRule login/?$ login.php [NC,L]
because everything was in a subfolder :)

Comment: You can answer your own questions too.

Comment: thank you CGeorges , i answered now but tomorrow can i chose that answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteBase subfolder/app/
RewriteRule login/?$ login.php [NC,L]
```

because everything was in a subfolder :)